# What are some common Java pitfalls/gotchas for C++ programmer?

Tags: java, c++, language-switching

As the question says, what are some common/major issues that C++ programmers face when switching to Java? I am looking for some broad topic names or examples and day to day adjustments that engineers had to make. I can then go and do an in-depth reading on this.

I am specifically interested in opinions of engineers who have worked in C++ for years and had to work with Java but any pointers from others or even book recommendations are more than welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- In C++ you'd use destructors to clean up file descriptors, database connections and the like.  The naive equivalent is to use finalizers.  Don't.  Ever.

Instead use this pattern:

```
OutputStream os;
try {
  os = ... 
  // do stuff
} finally {
  try { os.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

You'll end up doing stuff like that a lot.

- If you specify no access modifer, **in Java the members are package-private by default**, unlike C++ in which they are private.  Package-private is an annoying access level meaning it's private but anything in the same package can access it too (which is an idiotic default access level imho);
- There is no stack/heap separation.  Everything is created on the heap (well, that's not strictly true but we'll pretend it is);
- There is no pass-by-reference;
- The equivalent to function pointers is anonymous interfaces.

Comment: Pass by reference / value is worth reading about: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html

Comment: Note that Java 7 has [the try-with-resources mechanism where you can write a class that integrates with it by implementing `AutoCloseable`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources#custom).

Answer (score 7):

My biggest hurdle crossing from C++ to Java was ditching procedural code. I was very used to tying all my objects together within procedures. Without procedural code in java, I made circular references everywhere. I had to learn how to call objects from objects without them being dependents of each other. It was the Biggest hurdle but the easiest to overcome.

Number 2 personal issue is documentation. JavaDoc is useful but to many java projects are under the misconception that all that is needed is the JavaDoc. I saw much better documentation in C++ projects. This may just be a personal preference for documentation outside of the code.

Number 3. There are in fact **pointers** in java, just no **pointer arithmetic**. In java they are called **references**. Don't think that you can ignore where things are pointing at, it will come back with a big bite.

- **== and .equals are not equal.**
- == will look at the pointer(reference) while .equals will look at the value that the reference is pointing at.

Comment: can you please explain the type of circular references you can use in C++ but not in Java?

Comment: I will edit to clarify. What i was trying to say was that when I first started coding in java I started making circular references because I could not code procedurally. It is considered, as least by the developers that I know, bad form to make circular references.

Answer (score 5):

[Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) (instead of templates), specifically the way they were implemented using [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention book recommendations, definitely read [Effective Java, 2nd ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)—it addresses most of the pitfalls I've seen listed in the answers.

Comment: Second this. This a great little book that is written to answer the questions you have (pitfalls, gotchas and best practices).

Answer (score 5):

Creating a reference by accident when one was thinking of a copy constructor:

```
myClass me = new myClass();
myClass somebodyElse = me; /* A reference, not a value copied into an independent instance! */
somebodyElse.setPhoneNumber(5551234);
/* Hey... how come my phone doesn't work anymore?!?!?  */
```

Comment: I imagine that a C programmer is one of the most equipped to understand this, given their intimate relationship with pointers and reference values.

Answer (score 4):

- No multiple inheritance, and every class implicitly derives from java.lang.Object (which has a number of important methods you definitely have to know and understand)
- You can have a sort of multiple inheritance by implementing interfaces
- No operator overloading except for '+' (for Strings), and definitely none you can do yourself
- No unsigned numerical types, except char, which shouldn't really be used as a numerical type. If you have to deal with unsigned types, you have to do a lot of casting and masking.
- Strings are not null-terminated, instead they are based on char arrays and as such are immutable. As a consequence of this, building a long String by appending with += in a loop is O(n^2), so don't do it; use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Plus: no option to 'pass by value' for objects.

Answer (score 3):

Getting used to having a garbage collector.  Not being able to rely on a destructor to clean up resources that the GC does not handle.

Everything is passed by value, because references are passed instead of objects.

No copy constructor, unless you have a need to clone.  No assignment operator.

All methods are virtual by default, which is the opposite of C++.

Explicit language support for interfaces - pure virtual classes in C++.

Answer (score 2):

It's all the little bitty syntax differences that got me.  Lack of destructors.

On the other hand, being able to write a main for each class (immensely handy or testing) is real nice; after you get used to it, the structure and tricks available with jar files are real nice; the fact that the semantics are completely defined (eg, int is the same everywhere) is real nice.

Answer (score 2):

My worst problem was keeping in mind the ownership of memory at all times. In C++, it's a necessary thing to do, and it creates some patterns in developer's mind that are hard to overcome. In Java, I can forget about it (to a very high degree, anyway), and this enables some algorithms and approaches that would be exceedingly awkward in C++.

Answer (score 2):

There are no objects in Java, there are only references to objects. E.g :

```
MyClass myClass;   // no object is created unlike C++.
```

But :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();   // Now it is a valid java object reference.
```

Answer (score 1):

The best book of Java "gotchas" that I've read is [Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X).  It's **not** specifically aimed at C++ developers, but it is full of examples of things you want to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

All methods are virtual.

Parameterized types (generics) don't actually create code parameter-specific code (ie, `List<String>` uses the same bytecode as `List<Object>;` the compiler is the only thing that complains if you try to put an `Integer` in the former).

Varargs is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a method parameter as final doesn't mean what you at first think it means

```
private void doSomething(final MyObject myObj){
   ...
   myObj.setSomething("this will change the obj in the calling method too");
   ...
}
```

because java is pass by value it is doing what you're asking, just not immediately obvious unless you understand how java passes the value of the reference rather than the object.

Answer (score 0):

Another notable one is the keyword `final` and `const`. Java defines the const as a reserved keyword but doesn't specify much of its usage. Also

```
object1=object2
```

doesn't copy the objects it changes the reference